# Application.InputBox pre-selects unexpected default range

Tags: excel, vba

I want the user to select a Range via `Application.InputBox` with `Type:=8`.
I give it a default range, but in some cases it shows an unexpected behaviour and pre-selects a different wrong default range.

My example code:

```
Dim myDefaultRange as Range
Dim myInputRange as Range

Set myDefaultRange = ActiveSheet.Range("C8")
Set myInputRange = Application.InputBox( _
  Title:="Exampe Title", _
  Prompt:="Example Prompt", _
  Default:=myDefaultRange.Address(0, 0), _
  Type:=8)
```

I expected my example to select cell C8 and ask like this:

[image: wish]

Instead column H is preselected and the user is asked for a new range for $H:$H like this:
[image: reality]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the default range for the `Application.InputBox` points to a cell in column C or R and you define it without $, then it's interpreted as **R1C1-notation** with a given `Column` or `Row`.
In your example the cell's address C8 is interpreted as column 8, i. e. column H.

The default range should be defined like this:

```
Default:=myDefaultRange.Address
```

By this, the default range in your example will be shown as $C$8 and `Application.InputBox` will preselect the desired default cell range.

Comment: Nice bug, MSFT :-)